# How to create a calendar in Vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to create a calendar in Vertica. However, there are complications with syntax. Please help to add whatever is needed.

```
create table calendar
 as select 10 as day, 10 as month, 1996 as year, date'2020-02-02' as date from dual;
delete from  calendar where 1=1;

begin
declare
    i date := date'2020-01-01';
begin
while ( i<=trunc(sysdate)) loop
begin
insert into calendar
select EXTRACT(DAY FROM i) as day,
       extract(month from i ) as month,
       extract (year from i) as year,
       i as date,
       DAYOFWEEK(i-1) as weekday
end;
i:=i+1;
end loop;
end;
 end;;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vertica's `TIMESERIES` clause.

Here's my complete `mkcalfromnothing.sql` script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cal;
CREATE TABLE cal (
  date_id                  INT         NOT NULL
, date_dt                  DATE        NOT NULL
, year_id                  SMALLINT    NOT NULL
, yearquarter_id           INTEGER     NOT NULL
, quarter_nbr              SMALLINT    NOT NULL
, yearmonth_id             INTEGER     NOT NULL
, month_nbr                SMALLINT    NOT NULL
, month_name               CHAR(10)    NOT NULL
, day_of_month_nbr         SMALLINT    NOT NULL
, yearweek_id              INTEGER     NOT NULL
, week_nbr                 SMALLINT    NOT NULL
, day_of_week_name         VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
, busday_flag              BOOLEAN     NOT NULL
, last_day_of_month_flag   BOOLEAN     NOT NULL
, last_day_of_quarter_flag BOOLEAN     NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO cal
WITH datelist AS (
SELECT dt::DATE AS dt
FROM (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2009-01-01' ts
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-12-31' ts
) lims
TIMESERIES dt AS '1 DAY' OVER(ORDER BY ts)
)
SELECT
  YEAR(dt)*10000+MONTH(dt)*100+DAY(dt) AS date_id
, dt                          AS date_dt                  
, YEAR(dt)                    AS year_id                  
, YEAR(dt) * 10 + QUARTER(dt) AS yearquarter_id           
, QUARTER(dt)                 AS quarter_nbr              
, YEAR(dt) * 100 + MONTH(dt)  AS yearmonth_id             
, MONTH(dt)                   AS month_nbr                
, TO_CHAR(dt,'Month')         AS month_name               
, DAY(dt)                     AS day_of_month_nbr         
, YEAR(dt)*10+WEEK(dt)        AS yearweek_id              
, WEEK(dt)                    AS week_nbr                 
, TO_CHAR(dt, 'Day')          AS day_of_week_name         
, DAYOFWEEK_ISO(dt) NOT IN (6,7) AS busday_flag              
, DAY(dt+1)=1                    AS last_day_of_month_flag   
, DAY(dt+1)=1 AND MONTH(dt+1) IN (1,4,7,10) AS last_day_of_quarter_flag 
FROM datelist;
```

Comment: Do you regard the question as answered? Can you mark it as answered?